# Use of set data-structure in C++ to detect cycles in graph

Tags: c++, graph, set

I've been working on an algorithm to detect cycles in an undirected weighted graph. Besides this, the graph doesn't have any self-loops. Two of the commonly used algorithms I've come across are

1. Union-Find Algorithm: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/union-find/
2. Union By Rank and Path Compression http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/union-find-algorithm-set-2-union-by-rank/

I am thinking to use set data structure to detect cycles in the graph. My approach is as follows:

My application is as folows:

```
1. Create an empty set S;
2. Visit an edge.
3. If both the source and destination vertices (connected by the undirected weighted edge in step 2) are there in set S, cycle is found else add both source and destination to set S and continue further till all edges are visited.
```

See : http://ideone.com/cQjv7c

In above ideone link,There's an edge of weight G[i].second between G[i].first.first and G[i].first.second.

Please suggest where or in what cases my approach can lack? If you could find any loop holes in my approach, please suggest.

Comment: What does it matter for cycles if the graph is weighted or not? The weak part is probably computational complexity my 1st hunch says its `O(E^2)`, not sure if this is good or not.

Comment: I think simple BFS or DFS with visit check have `O(V)`. And if you build a graph from scratch to change representation it would still be additional `O(E)`, so `O(E+V)`.

Comment: By just looking at your 3 steps pseudocode,
What if the graph is like this.
Nodes -> (1,2,3,4,5)
And the edges are stored this way and you take them one by one  in this particular order.
Edges -> ( (1,2) ,(2,3),(4,5),(3,4) )
At the last step you will get and edge with 2 vertices that you **have visited** but you will wrongly deduct that **there is** a circle
So the order you visit them really matters and you don't clearly tell the order that you are visiting each new edge.

Comment: @LanPac Ohh! You're right! That's a big flaw in my approach!

Comment: @CPPCoder Happy to help you :D.
Now I believe you have alternatives to solve the problem.
Some already suggested some.